# Python PyQt: TypeError while pressing the button to change the color of Circle

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qpainter

I am new in Python and using PyQt4 for developing the Gui. I want to change the color of circles while pressing the toggle button. But I am getting the error in slot.

My code is:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MyFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.scene=QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(QRectF(0,0,245,245))
        self.bt=QPushButton("Press",self)
        self.bt.setGeometry(QRect(450, 150, 90, 30))
        self.bt.setCheckable(True)
        self.color = QColor(Qt.green)
        self.color1= QColor(Qt.magenta)
        self.show()
        self.connect(self.bt, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.changecolor)

    def paintEvent(self, event=None):
        paint=QPainter(self)
        paint.setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt.magenta),1,Qt.SolidLine))
        paint.setBrush(self.color)
        paint.drawEllipse(190,190, 70, 70)
        paint.setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt.green),1,Qt.SolidLine))
        paint.setBrush(self.color1)
        paint.drawEllipse(300,300, 70, 70)

    def changecolor(self):
        if pressed:
         self.color = QColor(Qt.red)
         self.color1= QColor(Qt.blue)
        else:
         self.color=QColor(Qt.yellow)
         self.color1=QColor(Qt.gray)

        self.update()

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
f=MyFrame()
f.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way it stands, it tries to call changecolor with only one argument, self. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. Your changecolor takes in a variable "paint", but tries to use self.paint, which doesn't exist. So maybe you could think, that you can just get a hold of the painter with a call to to QPainter and lose the parameter called "paint", like following:

```
def changecolor(self):
  paint = QPainter(self)
  paint.setBrush(QColor(Qt.red))
  paint.drawEllipse(190,190,70,70)
  self.update()
```

This runs into the following error:

```
QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
```

That tells you, that you can only have painting actions inside the paintEvent. One solution is to have an class member, e.g. self.color that holds the color you want for the circle. A fully working code is below:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MyFrame(QWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QWidget.__init__(self)

    self.scene=QGraphicsScene(self)
    self.scene.setSceneRect(QRectF(0,0,245,245))
    self.bt=QPushButton("Press",self)
    self.bt.setGeometry(QRect(450, 150, 90, 30))
    self.color = QColor(Qt.green)
    self.show()
    self.connect(self.bt, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.changecolor)

  def paintEvent(self, event=None):
    paint=QPainter(self)
    paint.setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt.red),1,Qt.SolidLine))
    paint.setBrush(self.color)
    paint.drawEllipse(190,190, 70, 70)

  def changecolor(self):
    self.color = QColor(Qt.red)
    self.update()

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
f=MyFrame()
f.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Daniel, I have changed the code from simple push button to toggle button (as above in my post code, please have a look of the code) and want to change the color of my circles while pressing, I tried many combination but could not solve the problem, please suggest me how to solve it.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? "error in slot" is not really descriptive. Furthermore, I think that you shouldn't do what you just did, i.e. change the question asked, after getting an answer. Modifying the question so that it's clearer, reflects further attempts at solution etc. are fine, but now you have changed the question, and the answer doesn't apply to the question, as it stands. I feel it would be better to start a new question, since now you have a new question.

Comment: Ok I shall post it as a new question